# HQL combined "distinct" and "order by"

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, hql

This query works if I remove the "distinct" or the "order by", but it does not work combined. I am trying to follow examples. Can you please explain this?

```
String queryString = "select distinct event.county from Event as event order by event.county.county"

[main] - [ERROR] SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions():144 >> ERROR: for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list
  Position: 215
```

Generated SQL

```
select distinct county1_.Id as Id4_, county1_.County as County4_ from Event event0_ inner join County county1_ on event0_.CountyID=county1_.Id cross join County county2_ where event0_.CountyID=county2_.Id order by county2_.County
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try with

```
select distinct county from Event event
inner join event.county county
order by county.county
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically this error happens because Hibernate won't load all the data of your nested objects in your SELECT statement. It will only load their **id**, so it's data will be retrieved only if you call somewhere. This is a strategy to save memory resources, since the data will only be fetched, if actually needed.

You can change this behaviour by changing your JOIN to **FETCH JOIN**.

```
SELECT DISTINCT county FROM Event event JOIN FETCH event.count county ORDER BY county.county
```

A "fetch" join allows associations or collections of values to be initialized along with their parent objects using a single select.

More on the link below

[https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en-US/html/queryhql.html#:~:text=A%20%22fetch%22%20join%20allows%20associations%20or%20collections%20of%20values%20to%20be%20initialized%20along%20with%20their%20parent%20objects%20using%20a%20single%20select](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en-US/html/queryhql.html#:%7E:text=A%20%22fetch%22%20join%20allows%20associations%20or%20collections%20of%20values%20to%20be%20initialized%20along%20with%20their%20parent%20objects%20using%20a%20single%20select).